# Using Pymongo Upsert to Update or Create a Document in MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a dataframe that contains data I want to upload into MongoDB. Below is the data:

```
    MongoRow = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'school': {1: schoolID}, 'student': {1: student}, 'date': {1: dateToday}, 'Probability': {1: probabilityOfLowerThanThreshold}})

                     school                   student        date  Probability
1  5beee5678d62101c9c4e7dbb  5bf3e06f9a892068705d8420  2020-03-27     0.000038
```

I have the following code which checks if a row in mongo contains the same student ID and date, if it doesn't then it adds the row:

```
def getPredictions(school):
    schoolDB = DB[school['database']['name']]
    schoolPredictions = schoolDB['session_attendance_predicted']
    Predictions = schoolPredictions.aggregate([{
        '$project': {
            'school': '$school',
            'student':'$student',
            'date':'$date'
        }        
    }])
    return list(Predictions)
Predictions = getPredictions(school)
Predictions = pd.DataFrame(Predictions)

schoolDB = DB[school['database']['name']]
collection = schoolDB['session_attendance_predicted']
import json

for i in Predictions.index:
    schoolOld = Predictions.loc[i,'school']
    studentOld = Predictions.loc[i,'student']
    dateOld = Predictions.loc[i,'date']
    if(studentOld == student and date == dateOld):
        print("Student Exists")
        #UPDATE THE ROW WITH NEW VALUES
    else:
        print("Student Doesn't Exist")
        records = json.loads(df.T.to_json()).values()
        collection.insert(records)
```

However if it does exist, I want it to update the row with the new values. Does anyone know how to do this? I have looked at pymongo upsert but I'm not sure how to use it. Can anyone help?

'''''''UPDATE'''''''

The above is partly working now, however, I am now getting an error with the following code:

```
dateToday = datetime.datetime.combine(dateToday, datetime.time(0, 0))

MongoRow = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'school': {1: schoolID}, 'student': {1: student}, 'date': {1: dateToday}, 'Probability': {1: probabilityOfLowerThanThreshold}})
data_dict = MongoRow.to_dict()

for i in Predictions.index:
    print(Predictions)
    collection.replace_one({'student': student, 'date': dateToday}, data_dict, upsert=True)
```

Error:

```
InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To upsert you cannot use `insert()` (deprecated) `insert_one()` or `insert_many()`. You must use one of the [collection level operators](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) that supports upserting.

To get started I would point you towards reading the dataframe line by line and using [`replace_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) on each line. There are more advanced ways of doing this but this is the easiest.

Your code will look a bit like:

```
collection.replace_one({'Student': student, 'Date': date}, record, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @BellyBuster. So does that line of code check whether the student and date exists in a row in the mongo collection? If it does upsert it? Would this then replace my if statement?

Comment: Ok great, if it doesn't exist, will it insert the row, or do I need to add in more code for that?

Comment: If it can't find a match according to the filter criteria (e.g. `{'Student': student, 'Date': date}`) it will insert a record, and if it does find a match it will overwrite the existing record with the new record.

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: replacement must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

Comment: Your `record` that you are upserting must be a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @BellyBuster. I'm now getting this error - InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: datetime.date(2020, 3, 27), of type: <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: you need to convert your date to a datetime using `datetime.datetime.combine(<YOUR_DATE>, datetime.time(0, 0))`

Comment: I added that line of code in, but got this error - InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210432/discussion-between-pippa97-and-belly-buster).

Answer (score 19):

Probably a number of people are going to be confused by the accepted answer as it suggests using `replace_one` with the `upsert` flag.

Upserting means 'Updated or Insert' (Up = update and sert= insert). For most people looking to 'upsert', they should be using `update_one` with the `upsert` flag.

For example:

```
collection.update_one({'matchable_field': field_data_to_match}, {"$set": upsertable_data}, upsert=True)
```