# How insert data to mongodb without duplicates

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

How can I insert data into mongodb again without duplicates?

For example, I did change my file, and I need to insert it into my database without old info

```
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient

lst = []

with open('qAfpxiFfaq31nRfqWiYnKiJRW7IRiyx6.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        title_dict = {
            "id": row["п»їid"],
            "source_name": row["source_name"],
            "title": row["title"],
            "source_url": row["source_url"],
            "language": row["language"],
            "contry": row["country"],
            "published_at": row["published_at"]
        }
        lst.append(title_dict)
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        db = client['Parser']
        collection = db['csv']
        collection.update(title_dict)
```

Comment: you need to make the field "unique" when defining the schema

Comment: Use an update statement with the UPSERT option.  If the record does not exist it will create it, but if it does exist it will update the original rather than inserting again.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883397/using-pymongo-upsert-to-update-or-create-a-document-in-mongodb-using-python